# Changing background image with javascript (webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack

Any one know how to set the background image with javascript when using webpack?  (I think it is a webpack issue) I have tried setting the css directly with .style.backgroundImage and have also tried by using css variable but neither is working. The css variable works with the default value set in the css but when I try to change the var with javascript it is not working. here is the code i have been trying to use

```
import waldo2 from './images/waldo2resize.jpg'

const addPic = (picture) => {

    const picContainer = document.createElement('div');
    picContainer.id = 'picContainer'
    picContainer.classList.add('svgContainer');
    const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.id = 'container';
    //const image = new Image();
    //image.src = waldo2;
   //svg.style.backgroundImage = "url(waldo2)"
   document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--myVariable', 'url(./images/waldo3.jpg)');
    picContainer.appendChild(svg)

    document.body.appendChild(picContainer);
}



export default addPic;
```

here is the css

```
:root{ --myVariable : url(./images/waldo2.jpg) }

body {
    
}


.svgContainer {}

#container {

    height: 1926px;
    width: 2500px;
    background-image: var(--myVariable);
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

i get this error when trying to change the variable      GET file:///home/vboxuser/repos/waldovjs/dist/images/waldo3.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

If i set the variable with the same value (that is in the javascript) to the default in css it works fine

Answer (score 0):

template literal worked

```
const addPic = (picture) => {

    const picContainer = document.createElement('div');
    picContainer.id = 'picContainer'
    picContainer.classList.add('svgContainer');
    const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.id = 'container';
    //const image = new Image();
    //image.src = waldo2;
   //svg.style.backgroundImage = "url(./images/waldo2.jpg)"
   svg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${waldo2})`
   document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--myVariable', waldo2);
  
    picContainer.appendChild(svg)

    document.body.appendChild(picContainer);
}
```